# Datatables with jQuery-toggles not working on pages other than page 1

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, datatables

I have a Data-table that is being populated with server-side code.

```
<table id="email_alerts" class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.crmContactsList)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.fname</td>
                <td>
                    @if (item.claimsOpenedAlert)
                    {
                        <div class="control-label">
                            <div class="toggle toggle-primary" data-toggle-on="true" data-contact-id="@item.crmContactID"></div>
                        </div>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <div class="control-label">
                            <div class="toggle toggle-primary" data-toggle-on="false" data-contact-id="@item.crmContactID"></div>
                        </div>
                    }
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I use this jQuery to initialize all of the jQuery Toggles to be set to what the database returned.

```
jQuery('.toggle').each(function () {
            $(this).toggles({
                on: $(this).data('toggle-on')
            });
        });
```

I use this code to alter their state when they are clicked on.  Off goes to on and vice versa.

```
// Toggle Switches
        $('.toggle').on('click', function () {
            console.log($(this).data('toggle-on'));
            if ($(this).data('toggle-on') == true) {
                $(this).data('toggle-on', false)
                console.log('Turning off ' + $(this).data('contact-id'));
            }
            else {
                $(this).data('toggle-on', true)
                console.log('Turning on ' + $(this).data('contact-id'));
            }
        });
```

Now all of this works perfectly, except when I click on any page other than the first page for Data-tables.  Page 2+ they all default to being turned on.

Any idea why this works for the first page but not for other pages in data-tables?

Comment: Where do you call the the toggle binding code? Sounds like the subsequent pages aren't getting the toggle events bound. You need to call it after each table draw, ideally in a datatable callback function like `fnRowCallback`

Comment: @markpsmith I think that was the first part of the jQuery.  That takes all .toggle classes and initializes the Toggle behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialise the toggles plugin dynamically, so you also "toggles" elements injected when changing page, sorting etc :

```js
jQuery('#example').on('draw.dt', function() {
    jQuery('.toggle').each(function() {
        $(this).toggles({
           on: $(this).data('toggle-on')
        });
    });
});
```

You must also use a delegated event handler. As it is now, you only have a click-handler for the toggles on the first page :

```js
$('#example').on('click', '.toggle', function () {
    console.log($(this).data('toggle-on'));
    if ($(this).data('toggle-on') == true) {
        $(this).data('toggle-on', false)
        console.log('Turning off ' + $(this).data('contact-id'));
    } else {
        $(this).data('toggle-on', true)
        console.log('Turning on ' + $(this).data('contact-id'));
    }
});
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/gmptpbqg/** where all `.toggle` elements become "toggled" and on / off state is remembered correctly across the pages.

Comment: I was able to get it to work using the above code.  For some reason however I had to also use my ('.toggle').each part as well as yours.  With just yours my first page was messed up.  With just mine anything after the first page was messed up.  With both it seems to be working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a DataTable callback function like this:

```
$('#email_alerts').DataTable( {

    "scrollCollapse": true,
    "paging":         true,
    "fnDrawCallback": function() {
        jQuery('.toggle').bootstrapToggle();
    }

} );
```

It works fine for me. Good luck!!!

Answer (score 0):

Just sharing my answer since I am working with Bootstrap Toggle and not JQuery Toggle, but I used some of the accepted answer above:

```
$('#tblMyTable').on('draw.dt', function () {
            $('.myInputCheckBoxClass').bootstrapToggle();

            fncAdditionalBindingLogicForBoostrapToggle(); //In case you need any logic when you click the toggle button

        });
```

Below code doesn't work since whenever I click the pagination of DataTable, the bindings become erratic, so I used the modified version code above:

```
$('#tblCFRMode').on('draw.dt', function () {

              $('.myInputCheckBoxClass').each(function () {

              if ($(this).prop('checked') == true) {
                $(this).bootstrapToggle('on');
              } else {
                $(this).bootstrapToggle('off');
              }
          });
      });
```